# Импорт obj модели в canvas(текстурирование)

Tags: 3d

Пытаюсь залоадить модель obj, всё получается, но появляется проблема с текстурированием. В общем, есть модель obj формата из blenderа, которую надо заимпортить в three js, при этом оставить изначальное качество модели, ну или хотя бы приблежённо что-то в этом роде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код: `

```
function addModel(pos) {
        const mtlLoader1 = new MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader1.load('./models/untitled4.mtl', function(mtlParseResult) {
        mtlParseResult.preload();
        const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(mtlParseResult);
        objLoader.load('./models/untitled4.obj', function(r12) {
              r12.position.x = 0;
            r12.position.y = 0.04;
            r12.position.z = 0;
            r12.rotation.y = 1.55;
            r12.scale.x = 10;
            r12.scale.y = 10;
            r12.scale.z = 10;
            r12.isDraggable = true;
            scene.add(r12);
      });
    });
}
```

`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это в блендер исправляется.  UV развертка объектов делается, потом текстура позиционируется, масштабируется.. Судя по фото она вытянута ..

Comment: Очень сильно советую вам не маятся с .obj и подгружать именно [GLTF](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=contro#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) модели, куча проблем уйдёт сразу)

Comment: Еще проще работать с .glb форматом, один файл в отличии от .gltf.. При загрузке .gltf каждая картинка  текстур грузится отдельным запросом. Настроить отслеживание прогресса загрузки модели и отображать проценты к примеру, так же проще у .glb... Экспортировать оба формата можно из блендер, возможно понадобится включить аддон import-Export: gLTF 2.0 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJ модели не очень удобно импортировать. Сам когда-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, что после импорта ломается развертка и грузится только один материал. Чтобы импорт модели производился корректно я использовал `THREE.LoadingManager` и подгружал геометрию и материалы асинхронно.

Попробуйте такой вариант загрузки, должно работать:

```js
const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(loadingManager);
const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(loadingManager);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

/**
* Вернет Promise<THREE.Group>.
* THREE.Group можно будет добавить в сцену;
*/
function loadModel(path, basename) {
 return mtlLoader.setPath(path)
                 .setResourcePath(path)
                 .loadAsync(`${basename}.mtl`)
                 .then((materials) => {
                   materials.preload();
                   return materials;
                 })
                 .then((materials) => {
                   return objLoader.setPath(path)
                                   .setMaterials(materials)
                                   .loadAsync(`${basename}.obj`);
                 });
}

loadModel('./models/', 'untitled4').then((group) => {
           scene.add(group);
         })
         .catch(console.error);
```

Обязательно проверьте правильность пути до файлов текстур в файле `*.mtl`. Blender может указать его не совсем верно.

Comment: странная дичь, практически всё осталось как оно и есть ._. Есть догадки, почему оно может быть? прост с gltf форматом та же самая дичь

Comment: @Leonel можно только догадываться в чем причина. Попробуйте поочередно отключать ноды в шейдинге, может там что-то не так экспортируется.

Comment: я заметил тему, типо при экспорте модели и повторном импорте в blender, отсутствуют некоторые текстуры, но при этом всегда остаётся base color

Comment: @Leonel "с gltf форматом та же самая дичь".. Причем тут THREE.js, если проблема с текстурой наблюдается в блендер, еще до экспорта.. THREE.js всё отображает, текстура наложена и неправильно масштабирована, она вытянута по одной из осей, это скорее всего правиться  в UV развертке, выделяешь меш на котором вытянута текстура, жмешь S и выбираешь ось X|Y|Z масштабируешь до правильного отображения..

Comment: @Rudi ща правку внесу по вопросу, уберу js, здесь тема сейчас осталась ток с моделью, я хз почему, но не экспортируется n_diff и остальные текстуры, за исключением base color